# Is there a possibility to perform a reset test with a dynlm object in r

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, autoregressive-models

The resettest() function from lmtest-package seems to work only for lm objects but not for dynlm objects.

How is it possible to perform a reset-test with a dynlm-object?

Answer (score 0):

The resettest function can be used in dynamic models. the dynlm function returns the same list as lm does.

```
 m<-dynlm(d(Yus)~L(lrexus,2),datats)   
 resettest(m,power = 2,data = datats)
```

The results are exactly the same as Eviews output. Essentially dynlm() should be used for time-series data.